# How to create Back button in Excel to move user in the position he came from?

Tags: excel

Let me know please if the scenario feasible: user clicks on `Sheet1!A1` cell with "Go Details" button and it moves him to `Sheet2!B1`, where he may click "Back" button in the same row to be moved back to `Sheet1!A` row he came from. Same way he can click `Sheet1!J1` cell with "Go Details" button which moves him to the same `Sheet2!B1` row, but this time "Back" button leads him back to `Sheet1!J` row, so that it remembers the position user came from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert this code in the `ThisWorkbook` routine:

```
Private rngLastLink As Range

Private Sub Workbook_SheetFollowHyperlink(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    If UCase(Target.Parent.Value) = "BACK" Then
        If rngLastLink Is Nothing Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Target.Follow
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        Else
            rngLastLink.Worksheet.Activate
            rngLastLink.Activate
        End If
    Else
        Set rngLastLink = Target.Parent
    End If
End Sub
```

It will store the cell from any pressed hyperlink that is not called "Back". If "Back" is pressed, it will reactivate this cell.

Answer (score 3):

If the user, selects Excel Options > Quick Acccess Toolbar > All Commands.  Add "Back" and "Foward" they will have back and forward navigation after jumping links, just like on a web page.

Comment: Does not work for me unfortunately, the button should be in a row according to the scenario I described, not on toolbar, we can not manage user's toolbar. However can I imitate this Back button click with VB macro for instance?

Comment: I don't think the back/forward buttons will work like this in Excel - at least it does not go back to the previous selection. :-( Though I really wish this would be a standard feature in Excel.

Comment: Give it a try, it works for me.  Takes me to the last cell linked from, same sheet or different.  It least it does in Excel 2010

Comment: It works for me too, the only problem we can not ask every user to add this button to toolbar, so we need to imitate this button behavior. Os I wonder how can I run it

Comment: @JamesJenkins: My bad. I was hoping for a "back to your last selection" functionality, i.e. something that also works when you're manually selecting a new cell.

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to create a new button, then the assign macro screen will pop up once the button is successfully created.

Copy this code

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Worksheets("sheet2").Activate
End Sub
```

as macro

change sheet2 as appropriate for your scenario.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
Sheets.Select
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
ActiveSheet.Select
```

will synchronize entire row between worksheets - will only fire when you change worksheets...

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target
As Range)
Sheets.Select
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
ActiveSheet.Select
End Sub
```

will fire every time user change cells in active sheet.

Comment: I do not see how it is related to my task to create Back button with dynamic address To

Comment: Where is back button? I need the Back button to be in row user came into. And what do you mean by rows synchronization?

Answer (score 0):

I used Alt-Left arrow to go back.

```
Sub GoBackToWhereverYouCameFrom()
    Application.SendKeys ("%{LEFT}")
End Sub
```